# looping over pandas dataframe to create dummies

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a dataset which looks like following-

```
|      year     |     state   | election year 1-yes|
|---------------|-------------|--------------------|
|          2010 |     haryana |          1         | 
|          2010 |     haryana |          1         | 
|          2010 |     up      |          0         | 
|          2011 |     goa     |          1         |
|          2012 |     haryana |          0         | 
|          2012 |     up      |          1         | 
|          2013 |     up      |          0         |
|          2013 |     up      |          0         |
|          2013 |     haryana |          1         |
|          2015 |     haryana |          0         |
|          2015 |     up      |          0         |
```

The third column tells if there is an election in that particular state in that particular year. Haryana has election in 2010, so 1, but goa and up do not have any election in 2010, so the election year is 0 for them.

I want a loop which can add another column which tells the number of years until next election. So, when there is a election in haryana in 2010, it will be 0 (as the election is scheduled in this year only) and in 2012, it will be 3 as next election is in 2015. So, the required column has a range from 0 to 4 for all the states.

The table below summarizes my desired output.

```
| year |  state | election year 1-yes| years until next election|
|------|--------|--------------------|--------------------------|
| 2010 |haryana |          1         |            0             |
| 2010 |haryana |          1         |            0             |
| 2010 |  up    |          0         |            2             | 
| 2011 | goa    |          1         |            0             | 
| 2012 |haryana |          0         |            3             | 
| 2012 |  up    |          1         |            0             |
| 2013 |  up    |          0         |            4             | 
| 2013 |  up    |          0         |            4             |
| 2013 |haryana |          0         |            2             |
| 2015 |haryana |          1         |            0             |
| 2015 |  up    |          0         |            2             |
```

I am looking for a simple code loop on year and state as my data has over 30 states and 12 years.

Comment: chk your data. you desired output has different state column

Comment: 2013 up = 4? is it current?

Comment: this means that UP will have its next election in 4 years. as it had last in 2012

Comment: then why 2010-haryana has 0?  looks next elecion of haryana is 2013.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, I guess now I have edited it right

Comment: your example still wrong.  2013-haryana  is 1 in example and it has 0 in desired output. plz chk your data before asking. make data into code, like me and
 use short column name. we don need long column name with white space to answer it. make code messy. you make answerer waste unnecessary time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
data = [[2010, 'haryana', 1], [2010, 'haryana', 1], [2010, 'up', 0],
        [2011, 'goa', 1], [2012, 'haryana', 0], [2012, 'up', 1],
        [2013, 'up', 0], [2013, 'up', 0], [2013, 'haryana', 0],
        [2015, 'haryana', 1], [2015, 'up', 0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['year', 'state', 'election'])
```

`df`

```
    year    state   election
0   2010    haryana 1
1   2010    haryana 1
2   2010    up      0
3   2011    goa     1
4   2012    haryana 0
5   2012    up      1
6   2013    up      0
7   2013    up      0
8   2013    haryana 0
9   2015    haryana 1
10  2015    up      0
```

**Code**

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates().copy()
cond1 = df1['election'].eq(0)
s = (df1['election'].mask(cond1).mask(~cond1, df['year'])
     .groupby(df1['state']).bfill())
df1['next'] = s.mask(~cond1, 0).mask(cond1, s.sub(df1['year']))
```

`df1`

```
    year    state   election    next
0   2010    haryana 1           0.0
2   2010    up      0           2.0
3   2011    goa     1           0.0
4   2012    haryana 0           3.0
5   2012    up      1           0.0
6   2013    up      0           NaN
8   2013    haryana 0           2.0
9   2015    haryana 1           0.0
10  2015    up      0           NaN
```

merge df and df1

```
df.merge(df1, how='left')
```

result:

```
    year    state   election    next
0   2010    haryana 1           0.0
1   2010    haryana 1           0.0
2   2010    up      0           2.0
3   2011    goa     1           0.0
4   2012    haryana 0           3.0
5   2012    up      1           0.0
6   2013    up      0           NaN
7   2013    up      0           NaN
8   2013    haryana 0           2.0
9   2015    haryana 1           0.0
10  2015    up      0           NaN
```

Comment: hey, thanks for this awesome code. It is working perfectly for my data set. Much appreciate your effort.