# Pandas is giving me problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So as seen in the pictures I am trying to merge these two columns (Country and Description) and while yes it does merge successfully, it deletes the field that says incoming(in the Description column) because it has nothing in the country column corresponding to it.

How do I merge it without deleting the incoming cell?

Merge method, table is called Transactions

[image: Merge method, table is called Transactions]

Table columns that I am merging

[image: Table columns that I am merging]

Result of merge (incoming cells are deleted)

[image: Result of merge (incoming cells are deleted)]

Wanted to merge the columns so that if the country is not inserted in there it would just insert the cell from the Description column.

Transactions["CountryAProvider"] = (Transactions["Country"] +" "+ Transactions["Description"].astype(str))

Comment: make your example to code, not image

Comment: Sorry i am new to stackoverflow and just inserted it at the end.

Comment: answerer run your code and answer. so we need your example(`Transactions`) of code for answer. make `Transactions` to dataframe and provide the code like following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74719787/looping-over-pandas-dataframe-to-create-dummies/74720807#74720807

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See also: ["how to format a table in a post"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716/11107541). Please also read [ask] to learn how to write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`panda.Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) before the concatenation.

Try one of these two solutions :

```
Transactions["CountryAProvider"] = (Transactions["Country"].fillna("").astype(str) + " " + Transactions["Description"].fillna("").astype(str)).str.strip()
```

Or,

```
Transactions["CountryAProvider"] = Transactions[["col1", "col2"]].fillna("").astype(str).agg(" ".join).str.strip()
```